# What is the range of $f^{-1}$ where $f(z)=\frac{1}{2}(z+\frac{1}{z})$?

Tags: complex-analysis

Consider the complex function $f(z)=\frac{1}{2}(z+\frac{1}{z})$ which is conformal except at $-1,1$. This function maps the unit disk to $D=\mathbb{C}-[-1,1]$. Moreover it maps the exterior of the unit disk to the same $D$. My question is, if we consider $f^{-1}$ on $D$, then what is the range of $f^{-1}$? Is it the unit disk or the exterior of the unit disk?

Comment: What do you mean by $f^{-1}$? If $f$ is not a bijection, then $f^{-1}$ isn't a well-defined expression.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f_1(z)$ be the same as $f(z)$, but only defined for $z$ in the unit disk.  Let $f_2(z)$ be the same as $f(z)$, but only defined for $z$ on the exterior of the unit disk.
Both $f_1(z)$ and $f_2(z)$ are one-to-one, so they have inverses, which go back to their own domains.
$f(z)$ is not one-to-one, so it doesn't have an inverse.

Answer (score 0):

The set you seek can't just be the exterior of the unit disk since you say $f$ maps the unit disk to $D$, plus for example $f(1/2)={1\over 2}(1/2+2)=5/4$.  (Although I don't see how $f$ maps $0$ into $D$, but let's leave that aside for a moment.)  Given the common mathematical usage of $f^{-1}(A)$ to denote the set of points that $f$ maps to $A$, even if $f$ is not bijective, what we really want is the set of $z\in \mathbb{C}$ such that $f(z)\in D$. That requires us to determine all $z$ for which $-1\le f(z)\le1$.

Write $z=a+bi\ne 0$.  Then $\mathrm{Im}\,(1/z)=-b/(a^2+b^2)$, and so $z+1/z$ is real iff $b=b/(a^2+b^2)$, i.e., iff $|z|=1$ or $b=0$.

Suppose first $|z|=1$.  We then have $1/z=\overline{z}$, and so $z+1/z=2a$, and thus ${1\over2}(z+1/z)\in [-1,1]$ automatically.

Now suppose $z$ is real.  Then $z+1/z$ goes to $+\infty$ as $z\to+\infty$ and $z\to 0^+$, and similarly $z+1/z$ goes to $-\infty$ as $z\to-\infty$ and $z\to 0^-$.  Its derivative is $1-1/z^2$ which has a zero only at $z=\pm 1$.  Thus, the minimum positive value is at $1$, and since that minimum value is $1$, we must have $z+1/z>1$ for all other positive $z$.  A similar result holds for negative $z$.  We conclude that all real $z$ except $0$, $1$, and $-1$ map to $D$.

In sum, the inverse image we are seeking is $\mathbb{C}\setminus (\{0\}\cup \{z:|z|=1\})$.